# Shimano R7000-FD compatible with 10 speed?

Tags: shimano, compatibility, derailleur-front

Is the Shimano R7000-FD compatible with a 10 speed chain / cassette?  I currently have the R7000 chainwheel on my bike and that seems to work with a 10 speed chain / cassette.  If I upgraded the FD as well, would that be compatible with the rest of the system in 10 speed?

I looked at the [compatibility chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.7?cid=C-453&acid=C-455) but was unclear on how to read it for this purpose.

Comment: Front derailleur compatibility (in regards to groupset) relates to the chain and the crankset that is used.  In the chart it shows that the FD-R7000 is compatible with 11 speed chains, and there are no remarks on the crankset.  If you share what crankset you have, it would be easier to post an answer.  The reality is that front derailleurs have quite a large tolerance (for example on the width of the chain) and often FD's work fine just outside the compatibility charts.

Comment: Hi - I have a 165mm R7000 crankset on the bike currently.  My bike fitter put that on my bike and said it was compatible with 10speed, and it seems to work just fine.  I'm contemplating an incremental upgrade to 11speed, and wondering what parts will play nice along the way.

Comment: Sorry, I now see you mentioned it as the chainwheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front derailleur compatibility (in regards to groupset) relates to the chain, the crankset and shifters that are used.  The 10 speed chain is almost the same width as a 11 speed chain, so I don't expect any issue (even though the compatibility chart you linked to does specify to use a 11 speed chain).

Your crankset is a FC R7000, which is already within the same groupset as the FD R7000.  Which also means you have a front derailleur that is currently compatible with the crankset, and in turn shifters that are compatible with the current front derailleur.

> If I upgraded the FD as well, would that be compatible with the rest of the system in 10 speed?

Yes, I don't see any issues in compatibility across your components.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: No problem.  What are your current shifters?

Comment: As best I can tell, they're Dura Ace bar end shifters (I'm on a TT bike right now).  Unclear which year / model though.  The existing FD / RD / Cassette appear to be Ultegra 6600.

Comment: Without knowing the exact model, I think it's safe to say it will work.  Just make sure it's not a shifter for a triple crankset (which hasn't been available in Dura Ace in a long time).